Schema compare on production database
I often use Azure Data Studio's Schema Compare in lower environments like dev and uat, to get information about the schemas, before I commence with making changes and/or testing.
I need to compare the production schema (source of truth for the schema), to the lower environments as well. But, how do I know, that when I run the Schema Compare, I do not impact the production system? How do I know that I would not cause downtime or loss of data?
Obviously, if I apply a schema update on prod, that would have an impact. But I'm not asking about that, but rather specifically the comparison operation itself.

I could not find a statement from MS in the docs, that clarifies if Schema Compare is meant to be ran against production databases.

See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077807/sql-query-to-return-differences-between-two-tables

@nbk Unfortunately not. What I need to do is compare schemas, not data.

I have no knowledge of exact mechanics, but my understanding is that schema compare uses the sys.* tables (like sys.tables, sys.columns, etc.) to compare the schema and will therefore be extremely lightweight.  The only impact I can see is if someone is actively modifying the schema at the same time.    I have done occasional schema compares against my (very busy) prod environment and have never encountered issues.

"How do I know that I would not cause...loss of data?" - How do you know when you sneeze, you wouldn't cause loss of data?


if Schema Compare is meant to be ran against production databases.

Yes. The intent is that you have a new schema version, use the schema compare with production to identify the changes that need to be made to apply those changes to production.
